# My archives page won't sort posts by month

Tags: query, query-posts, archives, archive-template

I'm trying to make my own theme and I've created an archive template that works fairly well. The template shows all posts, but the problem is that all posts will show if I go to /2018/11/ (posts were created in different months) even though I've added `monthnum` and `year` in my `query_posts`.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Blog Posts
*/
?>
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&monthnum='. get_query_var('month') .'&year='. get_query_var('year')); ?>

<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

      <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <p class="lead"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(500,500, 'class'  => " img-responsive center-block") ); ?></a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="featurette-divider"></div>

    </div><!-- /#post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?> -->

      <?php endwhile; ?>

  <div class="navigation">
    <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link(__('« Newer','example')) ?></span> <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older »','example')) ?></span>
  </div><!-- /.navigation -->

<?php else: ?>

  <div id="post-404" class="noposts">

      <p><?php _e('None found.','example'); ?></p>

    </div><!-- /#post-404 -->

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I see you're using `query_posts` instead of modifying the main query with the `pre_get_posts` filter, what was the reason for doing so? Note that using `query_posts` this way will break pagination. Also, your template appears to be implementing date archives, but those already exist in WP, and have their own templates, e.g. `date.php` `month.php` etc

Comment: @TomJNowell Good question that made me research more. I ended up using the main query instead.